# Looking for updates in Pentaho7.x for log 4j vulnerability and it's procedure

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-cde, pentaho-report-designer, pentaho-design-studio

We are currently using **pentaho 7.X**, after log 4j vulnerability we need a solution for that. Please let me know if we have any updates in **pentaho 7.x** after log4j issuse or we need to upgrade to latest version. If we need to upgrade to latest version, what is the steps?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

By now Hitachi Vantara hasn't published any patch for the Community Edition version, I don't know if they have provided a patch for the Enterprise Edition.

They are going to release the 9.3 version, I don't know if there's an official date. Maybe in the Community Edition of the 9.3 version the log4j libraries will be updated, look for the official release notes when it's published.